# Convert string into float PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, type-conversion

I have a column in a MySQL table that is a varchar. However the data in the column is representative of a float value. I want to know if there is an easy way to convert the string into a float without loosing the data. The problem is that there are leading zeros's that are complicating things for me.

Sample data:

```
"100"
"002"
"075"
"0300"
"0135"
```

Need to convert to:

```
1.00
0.02
0.75
0.300
0.135
```

When I try to convert by multiplying by a decimal the leading zeros are stripped off and 002 become 2.0 instead of 0.02. Complicating things more some of the string values are 3 characters and some are 4 characters.

I am using PHP 5.4.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Basic PHP integers: numbers with leading zeroes are treated as octal: 077 -> 63 (int) -> 0x3F (hex). `075 * 2` is `octal 75 * decimal 2` -> `decimal 61 * decimal 2` -> 122 decimal

Comment: You should solve that once and for all in the database itself; dividing by 100 or 1000 or 1000000, etc. depending on the length and the first character doesn't seem a very sustainable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select cast(insert(your_column, 2, 0, '.') as decimal(10, 3))
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it simply do casting. hope it helps.

```
$Myfloat = (float) $String;
```